# Backbone update nested attributes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a table that displays a collection of models that looks roughly like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Product",
  category: {
    id: 1,
    name: "CategoryName"
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: "Another Product",
  category: {
    id: 1,
    name: "CategoryName"
},
etc..
```

I can select a model from the table and perform an edit on its attributes in a modal. After I finish editing attributes I call save, close the modal and pass an event to refresh my table. In my table view I recieve an event and call `fetch` with `update: true`

```
App.vent.on("refresh:products", function() {
    return this.collection.fetch()({
        update: true
    });
});
```

However none of the nested attributes, in this case `category`, get updated without a hard refresh. How I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I think you have a not good logic here. Accoring your JSON the better way is to separate models (ProductModel, CategoryModel).

Comment: @AlexanderShlenchack, I'm not sure what do you mean. The product model is in a relation with a several other models, such as category, measurements, etc. I'm serializing the model with its all relatives in a nested way, although I can merge nested attributes into a parent tree like `category_name: "name` and `category_id: 1`, but how would I benefit from doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try passing `reset:true` as options to fetch

```
App.vent.on("refresh:products", function() {
    return this.collection.fetch()({
        reset: true
    });
});
```

This will stop backbone from merging the data received from the server.